# How to change menu bar color in premiere pro cc 2018 in windows 10?

Tags: premiere

I want to change the menu color in premiere pro cc 2018 from white to black so that it matches the inner interface.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/workspaces.html). You may not be able to change the appearance to the point where is also affects scroll bars, title bars and menus that aren't inside panels. I have highlighted the related section of text in that link below:

> **Brighten or darken the interface** You can lower the brightness, as when working in a darkened editing suite or when making color
>   corrections. Changing the brightness affects panels, windows, and
>   dialog boxes but does not affect scroll bars, title bars, and menus
>   that aren’t inside panels. In addition, the change doesn’t affect the
>   application background on Windows.
>
> Choose Edit > Preferences > Appearance (Windows) or Premiere Pro >
>   Preferences > Appearance (Mac OS). Drag the User Interface Brightness
>   slider to the left or right. Click Default to restore the default
>   brightness level.